# Elementary Probability: Expected Value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I must say, first, that this question IS a homework assignment and I do not wish an answer here, for I already posssess it. I want to know if there is a general procedure of simplification in this kind of exercise.

The original question is: Given a deck of $52$ cards (4 cards of each type from $1$ to $13$),  what is the expected value of the quantity of cards $1$ in a hand of $13$ cards?

Now, I know how to compute it

$$ E(X) = \sum x_i P(X=x_i)$$
With the $x_1 = 0,1,2,3,4$ and $P(X=x_i) = \binom{13}{x_i}x_i!\frac{48\cdot47\cdots (36+x_i)}{52\cdot 51 \cdots 40} = \frac{13!}{(13-x_i)!} \frac{39!}{52!}\frac{48!}{(35+x_i)!}$

(Where I may have made a mistake in $P(X=x_i)$ but that's not the issue)

My generalized question is: Given a random variable $X$ that reproduces this kind of no replacement experiment, is there a fast way to compute $E(X)$? A closed formula maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probability is:

$$\mathsf P(X=x) = \dfrac{{4\choose x}{48\choose 13-x}}{52\choose 13} = \dfrac{4!48!13!35!}{x!(4-x)!(13-x)!(35+x)!52!}$$

---

However, for this you should use the **Linearity of Expectation**, and the most useful tool of *indicator variables*.

Let $X_i\in\{0,1\}$ be the indicator that card $i$ is an ace for $i\in\{1,,,13\}$.  So $X=\sum_{i=1}^{13} X_i$

For *any* card: $\mathsf E[X_i] = \frac{1}{13}$.

Then by the **LoE**: $\mathsf E[X]=\mathsf E[\sum_{i=1}^{13} X_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{13}\mathsf E[X_i] = 1$

Comment: I knew there was a really simple way of doing it. But of course, indicator and linearity of expectation! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a question: Why does the sum of $X_i$ represents my variable (the number of aces)? As I see, $X = \sum X_i$ can have the maximum value of $13$, as my variable has the maximum value of $4$. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JonasGomes The joint probability distribution of the indicator variables prevents more than four of them being $1$ at the same time. However, the linearity of expectation means that we don't have to worry about what their joint pmf actually is when we want to know the expectation of the sum.